# Massive pk-pk ripple on output using isolated DC-DC converter module

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, isolation, switching-regulator, transient

I'm having a very odd issue using an integrated DC-DC isolated converter module.  As the module stabilizes, a massive pk-pk ripple is developing on both the output *and* the input.  At first we thought this might be induced by characteristics of the circuit it was supplying or its own supply, but even after completely removing the module and simply using it to drive a resistive load we are still seeing this symptom.  To be clear, the module *does* output exactly an average 4.995VDC given a 48VDC supply, but the ripple is 1.29V pk-pk!  Has anyone else seen this behavior before that might be able to offer some clues?  Scope shots and details below:

**DC-DC Module**

- PN: SHHD003A0A [Datasheet](http://apps.geindustrial.com/publibrary/checkout/SHHD003A0A?TNR=Data%20Sheets%7CSHHD003A0A%7Cgeneric)
- Mfg: ABB Embedded Power
- Input Range: (4:1) 18-75 VDC
- Output: 5 VDC / 3A

**Test Setup**

- DC-DC alone on a perf-board with oscilloscope prove connected across VOut+/VOut-
- BK Precision supply providing 48VDC to VIn+/VIn-
- Trim and Remote ON/OFF disconnected (open circuit)
- 1kOhm Resistor across VOut+/VOut- as "load"

This is a scope shot from VOut-.  Pk-pk noise is 1.29V.  The periodicity of the transient exactly matches the switching frequency of the DC-DC.

[image: VOut-]

This is a shot from VIn- where a similar transient is observed 6.67V pk-pk noise!

[image: VIn-]

### UPDATE 1

-- Removed for simplicity --

### UPDATE 2

To take our particular application circuit out of the equation, this is the test setup I am using (constructed using the shortest possible soldered connections on a perf-board):

[image: Testbed]

There seem to be two issues contributing.  One is the bench-top power supply being used which itself introduces significant ripple.  Second is defeating the DC-DC converter's isolation by shorting VIn- and VOut- together.  The three images show each condition.  Even the 180 mV pk-pk noise in the best case (powered by battery), while potentially acceptable in the application, is double the datasheet specification (75 mV)!

It just gets worse from there. Ripple is 460 mV pk-pk when the DC-DC is powered by a bench-top supply (with identical results from several other switching AC-DC converters I had lying around).  Finally, ripple worsens to 1030 mV pk-pk **if VIn- and VOut- are shorted to defeat isolation and bring input and output ground to the same reference** (while powered via battery).  What's going on here, is it possible this is just a marginally stable poorly designed DC-DC module?

Powered by battery, maintaining isolation:
[image: Battery power with isolation]

Powered by BK precision bench-top supply, maintaining isolation:
[image: Benchtop power with isolation]

Powered by battery, with isolation broken using an 18awg wire short directly from VIn- to VOut-:
[image: Benchtop power no isolation]

Comment: Try powering it off two or three 9V batteries and see what happens. Or a linear supply. Or just a different type of switching supply.

Comment: The first thing to ask yourself when probing with an oscilloscope is: where is the ground located? and Is it the right ground? and How good is my ground?

Comment: As @VoltageSpike is hinting, once you connect a 'scope probe to a circuit you (usually) no longer have isolation from ground. Strange things can happen. What do you see if you make ac and dc voltage measurements with a battery-operated meter?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Without seeing the wires in the circuit, the return path back to the battery might be causing common mode noise. Placing the ground at different points in the circuit would change what you see on the scope drastically. At any rate parasitics make a large difference in any switching circuit with high and fast currents, where you place the probes makes a difference.

Comment: Another possibility is that the supply has an output filter.  An output filter feeding a DC-DC (negative incremental input impedance) can cause instability and the kind of behavior you're seeing.  Google "Middlebrook criterion".   You could also try a big bulk cap right at the input to the module to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Did you add a 33uF capacitor on the input, as suggested in page 6 of the datasheet?

Comment: @JohnD I recently worked on a display where the 7805 was replaced with a switcher but they left the 2200µF cap on the output. It was oscillating like mad - replacing it with a 47µF tantalum in parallel with 100nF ceramic brought the ripple to less than a millivolt.

Comment: Liquid Plasmas, you need to respond to some of the questions asked here. (If you can't be bothered, I'm not sure why anyone else should be.) Please consider paying some attention to your question soon after writing it, as that's when others are more likely to ask clarifying questions of you.

Comment: @VoltageSpike, I thought this as well, and since we don't have a differential probe for our scope I had been defeating the isolation by connecting VIn- and VOut- via a 18 gauge wire.  Then using VIn- as the ground point for the scope.

Comment: @JohnD Thanks for the suggestion, the original design had a low-ESR electrolytic 47 uF cap directly at VIn+/- for this purpose.  Increasing the cap to triple that amount had no noticeable affect.

Comment: @jonk It's only been an hour and it does actually take some time to go mock up people's suggestion and make an edit ;)

Comment: @LiquidPlasmas Have you considered adding a zero at the output? (Provide some *small* but managed series resistance to the output cap.)

Comment: What happens if you draw more current from it, eg. 1A?

Comment: get a 2" by 1" section of single-sided PCB, and solder ALL the GNDs to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been some time since I opened this question but I wanted to share the ultimate solution to help others new to diagnosing switching mode power supply characteristics (many of the comments helped but @VoltageSpike and @Elliot Alderson really set me on the right path).

In the end this was mostly a matter of not understanding how to probe the transient voltages produced by an SMPS properly with an oscilloscope.  After reviewing several different references:

- EEVBlog bypass capacitor overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xicZF9glH0
- EEVBlog grounding strategies for single ended oscilloscope probes:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaELqAo4kkQ&t=821s
- EEVBlog measuring power supply ripple and noise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Edel3eduRj4
- CUI's guide on measuring ripple and noise with single ended probes: https://www.cui.com/blog/how-to-measure-ripple-and-transient-in-power-supplies

Using a "paper clip" ground to create the smallest possible measurement loop made a *dramatic* difference in the quality of my measurements! (as shown below)

[image: "Paper clip" probe ground]

Here is an example of the ripple and voltage transients which originally motivated me to post this question.  In this case the probe tip is applied to the 5V rail and the probe ground is connected to a grounded mounting hole several inches away using the probe's alligator grounding clip (pk-pk ripple is 386 mV):

[image: Large apparent pk-pk ripple due to poor probing strategy]

Now that same supply, with no other change and supplied power by a bench-top power supply, is probed using the "paper clip" ground point directly across the bypass capacitor nearest the output of the DC-DC SMPS 5V output (pk-pk ripple is 20.1 mV, *well* within the DC-DC module's specification):

[image: Actual pk-pk ripple with proper probing technique]

In the end, this new probing method even allowed me to pinpoint a previously un-diagnosed noise source in the form of an ornery charge-pump based TTL -> RS232 transceiver which could be squelched by adding a second 1 uF ceramic bypass capacitor near the source.